# 18.04 LTS User Permissions

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I run VirtualBox with my Bionic (18.04 LTS) as host. My VM/guest is Windows 7 Pro. I use it partly to run a Johnson Controls Metasys app for HVAC controls. I want to set up a Guest login so others can run it from my system as well. I set up the Guest user account, set the permissions on the VM folders and files to allow Guest access. The Guest account can start the VM, Win7 guest, and app. All functions of the app work except two of the three programming tools that are needed within the app. Everything works as it should when I'm logged in. Not so for the Guest account. Is there something I'm missing as far as the Guest User's permissions goes?

Comment: what is the tools you are using? and witch one not work?

Comment: HVAC PRO and GX-9100 won't start. CCT works fine. All of them will work if I elevate the respective users to Admin in the Win7 guest, even using the cloned VM. I'd rather not do that if I can help it.